# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail"

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

Serializer.py

```
from .models import Post
from rest_framework import serializers


class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='user-detail',
                                               source='profile',)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['url',
                  'title',
                  'slug',
                  'author',
                  'updated_on',
                  'content',
                  'created_on',
                  'status']
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


STATUS = (
    (0, "Draft"),
    (1, "Publish")
)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

blog/urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'post', views.PostList)

urlpatterns = [

    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('', views.PostList.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),

]
```

Project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpunG.png)

I've been sitting on this problem for a long time, I can not solve it in any way. There are already several questions on stackowerflow with this error but none helped me

Comment: The problem is that you need to create and register a viewset for the User model. Then it will be fixed. Or you can use a ModelSerializer instead and but then you lose the url field

Comment: At a second glance, it doesn't look like you've registered your User viewset, although I think you have one, unless you're following the docs tutorial?

Comment: @Swift Thanks, bro. Im change class PostSerializer. Im delete url in PostSerializer and add ModelSerializer to args. But, I see api in main page. I think it's problem in urls.py

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you don't have a viewset/url for the user model.

Option 1:
You can create a new viewset for the user model and register it with the router.

Option 2:
create and directly use the Userserializer on the PostSerializer like this

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        # import the user model
        model = User
        fields = ("id",)

class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='user-detail',
                                               source='profile',)
    author =  UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['url', 'title', 'slug',
                  'author', 'updated_on', 'content',
                  'created_on', 'status']
```

Read more here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects